# How to select a name from a nested list within a dictionary using a user generated input?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

The goal of this program is to allow the user to enter a name of their choosing to form a dictionary that the user generated in another function and perform various manipulations to it. This dictionary is based on a 3 digit id number chosen by the user with a nested list containing a user chosen name and age. The complied dictionary is represented id_dict4. One example of a possible number of id(s) names and ages:

```
{123: ['tom', 44.0], 321: ['kim', 22.0], 444: ['bob', 33.0], 777: ['bob', 66.0]}
```

My current problem is the user needs to be allowed to select any name (i.e. 'kim', 'bob') from the list within the dictionary, and said name - and id and age - is then deleted, and a new list is generated. If there are more than 1 of the same names (in this case 'bob') both bob(s) and id/age need to be deleted.

This is one I tried so far:

```
        name = input("Select a name you wish to delete: ")
        for name in id_dict4.values():
            if name in id_dict4[id]:
                del id_dict4[id]
                print(id_dict4)
            return id_dict4
```

and it generates a keyerror

I also tried this among every variation I could think of:

```
name = input("Select a name you wish to delete: ")
        for name in id_dict4.values():
            if name in [id_dict4[id][0]]:
                del [id_dict4[id]]
                print(id_dict4[id])
```

It just skips the whole thing like its not there

I am new to Python, so I apologize if this is an simple thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

```
data = {123: ['tom', 44.0], 321: ['kim', 22.0], 444: ['bob', 33.0], 777: ['bob', 66.0]}

name = input("Name: ")

# Set up a new data dict    
newdata = {}
for k, v in data.items():
    # If the inputted name isn't the first item in the value list, add this key:value to the new dict
    if v[0] != name.strip():
        newdata[k] = v

print(newdata)
```

You need to use a new dict here, since trying to change the existing dict while iterating will lead to: `RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration.`

Comment: Thank you this worked! The new dictionary does not update to the original dictionary outside of this function - so it prints the entire dictionary as if it was not deleted in the main program. Is there any way to get this new dictionary to override the old one for the main program?

Comment: Just replace it at the end - `data = newdata`